# How can I change my font size without it cropping on the screen?

Tags: screen

I have this screen https://www.adafruit.com/products/913

I have tried to do change fonts from `/usr/share/consolefonts/`
like this `setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat15-Terminus22x11.psf.gz`

But my vga screen cut command line image - how can I fix it ?

Also I have tried to write

```
console-width= 
console-height
```

in `/boot/config.txt` - nothing usefull

Comment: Can you provide any more information, such as an image,? It would help us to determine exactly what the issue is.

Comment: [Screen Pic](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27959883/IMG_0556.JPG) I just want words to carry over to the next line with this font size

Comment: The term I believe you're looking for is "Word-wrap" ?

Comment: yes^ I just want all symbols to be read

Comment: See http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md#overscan